# Need help setting localhost

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, localhost, httpd.conf

### Help!

I'm trying to convince my Apache to point `localhost` to `/Sites`. *What am I doing wrong?*

### httpd.conf settings

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/username/Sites"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

- DocumentRoot points to /Sites folder.
- Listen 80
- NameVirtualHost *

### Buggy Result

1. 10.0.0.4 results with /Sites folder.
2. 127.0.0.1 does the same.
3. **ERROR**: http://localhost results with /private/etc/apache2/.../htdocs

Answer (score 3):

I'm writing this shamefully, just for one reason: I found a thread with that question exactly, that ended with the user asking the questions saying "Got it working. Too ashamed to say what was the problem".

I nearly killed myself.

```
listen localhost:80
```

That's what I've been missing the whole time.
There, for future generations. Amen.

Comment: At least I got a glimpse inside Apache's famous gut configuration. Gotta look on the bright side of bugs.

Answer (score 0):

What does localhost resolve to?  It could legitimately be the IPv6 ::1, or anything in 127.0.0.0/8.

Comment: I have both of these (::1 localhost / 127.0.0.1 localhost) in .hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

Without more info, I can't say exactly why this is happening.  Apache is sensitive to the order in which virtual hosts are specified in its configuration.  However, I'd use  here.  Unless you want other name-based virtual hosts on 127.0.0.1.

Also, it may be useful for you to use the following command to see what Apache thinks of your virtual host configuration:

apache2 -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS

Depending on your particular system, the "apache2" command may be something else, like "httpd".  If you're running Windows, I don't know if it will work at all.

Comment: DUMP_HOSTS gives: *:* is a NameVirtualHost | default server localhost (/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:36) |         port * namevhost localhost (/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:36). Looks okay. The httpd-vhosts.conf is set as I mentioned in the question. What to do now?